# Generate SAML assertion with .NET

Tags: .net, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I need to generate a SAML assertion to be used with an SAP app. Is there anyway to generate a SAML assertion and sign it with a private key within .NET Framework or .NET Core?

I thought I saw sustainsys had a “stub idp” project that might be what I am looking for but I can’t seem to find it on GitHub

Comment: I've used [this](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) to integrate two different C# web apps with our internal AD FS SAML IdP, but it's not something I do often enough to tell you any more than, "it exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stub Idp is in the `v2` branch of the `Sustainsys.Saml2` repo. Unfortunately it is a .NET Framework MVC application and not .NET Core. But all the protocol work is done by the lower level `Sustainsys.Saml2` packages which runs on .Net Core.